# SQL Query that returns only records with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with two tables: `Customers` and `Services`.

The `Customer` table has account information and the `Services` table has individual records of every service my company has performed.

The `Services` table is linked to the `Customer` table with an `ID` column where `Customers.ID = Services.CustomerID`.

I am trying to perform a query which will return the customer name and account number for only those customers where more than one service has been performed within a specified date range. For example, show me all customers where I've performed work more than twice in 2015.

How do I write this type of query so that only those with multiple service visits are returned? I can do this using cursors, counting results, etc. but it seems there must be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `JOIN` and a `GROUP BY` like so:

```
SELECT Customers.ID
FROM Customers
JOIN Services ON Customer.ID=Services.CustomerID
--WHERE your Services date check here
GROUP BY Customers.ID -- you can add more columns from the customers table here and in the select as needed
HAVING SUM(1)>1
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause to filter the `Services`' date range (just before the `GROUP BY`).

Comment: not a big fan of `SUM(1)>1` though.. `HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1` makes more sense

Comment: @JamieD77, I guess that's a question of preference. I usually use SUM because it also allows to add conditionals like so: `SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. In the end it does the same here.

Comment: that's true!.. just like `COUNT(CASE WHEN condition THEN field END)`  lol  +1 either way

Comment: It is the same in the end but I have to say I also would prefer count(*). Mostly because the first glance at this I thought you were using ordinal position as opposed to the constant. Just took me a second or two to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

Select Id from Customers C where count (select * from Services S where C.id = S.CustomersId ) > 1

Comment: that's not really a valid query in SQL Server

Comment: Well, replace `COUNT(...)>1` with `EXISTS(...)` and you're good. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID
,Customers.Name
,Customers.AcoountNumber
FROM Customers 
JOIN 
(
    select Services.CustomerID, Services.CustomerID as totalServices
    from Services
    where Services.date BETWEEN @FROM_DATE AND @TO_DATE
    group by Services.CustomerID
    having count(Services.CustomerID) >1
) AS CustomersMoreThan1 on Customers.CustomerID=CustomersMoreThan1.CustomerID
```

This query allows you to add more columns from your Customer table without having to modify your GROUP BY.